# How to get the min and max values from a jquery ui slide ranger into 2 separate variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have a jquery ui slide ranger which has two prices. A min price and a max price. How can I put the min and max into seperate variables? I want to create if statements but not inside the slide ranger function but in a search button function. When the user clicks search, it will get the min price and the max price that the user selected and output results of products. Is this possible and how could i do this?

Here is my slide ranger code

```
$(function() {
  $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 249500,
    max: 750000,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount" ).val( "£" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - £" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }
  });
  $( "#amount" ).val( "£" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
    " - £" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get values min and max from jQueryUI Slider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408423/how-to-get-values-min-and-max-from-jqueryui-slider)

Comment: Your sample code already shows how to get the lower and upper values in the range: `$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 )` is the low value and `$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 )` is the high.

Comment: I've tried that but still no luck

Comment: Please show the code you tried that didn't work.

Comment: $(function(){
  $( "#Search" ).on("click", function(){  
 var minPrice = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 );
 var maxPrice = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 );
 
 //if statement here

Comment: Edit your question to show all of the code you're having trouble with. I can't tell how that relates to the code you've already put in your question.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot There is a magic link `[edit]` which might help new users to edit there questions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the `min` and `max` range of the slider using the [option](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-option) method as shown below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 249500,
    max: 750000,
    values: [75, 300000]
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    var min = $("#slider-range").slider("option", "min"),
      max = $("#slider-range").slider("option", "max")
    console.log("min: " + min+" max: " + max);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
<button>Search</button>
```

---

You can access the `min` and `max` of current range using the [`values`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-values) option as shown below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 249500,
    max: 750000,
    values: [75, 300000]
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    var min = $("#slider-range").slider("option", "values")[0],
      max = $("#slider-range").slider("option", "values")[1];
    console.log("low: " + min+" high: " + max);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
<button>Search</button>
```